# How to keep text over image at exactly center for any width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am trying to keep text at the center over the circle image, I have tried with following code it is center now but when I resize window or change view to ipad, iphone it gets shifted to left, can we manage this text exact center for any screen width?
Here is my code

```
            <div class="img-div-1 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
                <h4 class="city-name">MONTREAL</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 img-div-2">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
                <h4 class="city-name">PRAGUE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 img-div-3">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="">
                <h4 class="city-name">NEW YORK</h4>
            </div>
```

and css I tried for this is

```
.city-name{
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 46%;
    text-align: center;
    /* font-size: 2rem; */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I want to maintain text over the image at center for any screen, without writing custom code like media queries adjusting for each screen. If it is possible please provide some suggetions. Thank you so much for visiting

Here is [FiddleDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/p6r8by2j/)

Answer (score 0):

### Absolute and Relative Positions

When using **absolute** positions, keep in mind that you will always need a **Relative** position to contain it.
So your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="… relative"><!-- Relative position -->
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="">
    <h4 class="city-name">MONTREAL</h4> <!-- Absolute position -->
</div>
```

And your CSS should look like this: (I wrote notes for every important css rule)

```
div img{ /* This is for image fluid resizing. */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.relative{ position: relative; }
.city-name{
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute; /* Every absolute position should be contained by a relative position. */
    top: 0; /* Every position is set to 0. */
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* This will let your text be seen every time. */
    margin: auto; /* Margin will do the trick to center the content. */
    width: 100%; /* Width and Height is needed to let positions center the content. */
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center; /* Text align center because we used width: 100%; so we could writte any size text and it will be centered. */
    line-height: 1em; /* This is not important. */
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/w9L44gwL/1/

If you like my answer, please approve it by choosing it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Just give following css:

```
.img-div-1, .img-div-2, .img-div-3 {
 display: table-cell;
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
}
```

Change `.city-name` left property to `left: 50%;`

And give `h4`  `margin:0`.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6r8by2j/5/)**

Comment: it is not working, please check in fiddle only, its not in center

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere i can see in center. http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Othl.png. Please check agaian

Comment: Because of given width:auto, in bootstrap col-md-4 and sm,lg not taking actual width and there are 4 images are coming in a row for me. Yeah text is center but how to keep bootstrap standard width dont want width:auto, it taking 4 images in row

Comment: check this one I have 9 images totaly and 3 images per row i am placing https://jsfiddle.net/0ocutxn7/

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere than i think you should change html.

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere What you are trying to achieve. You should change your html structure.

Comment: the structure is simple sir, i have container in that I have created col-sm-4, col-sm-4 and col-sm-4. Inside each col-sm-4 i have a image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107923/discussion-between-sudarshan-kalebere-and-ketan).

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere But , element not become center depend on it's sibling. It will be center depend on parent element.